# Serialization and Deserialization of objects into varbinary in SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, serialization, stream, deserialization

I couldn't find an answer to this issue

Actually I am a Card Designer using C# Windows App
I want to save the user card into the database, so first I got all Card properties and tried to serialize it and put it on byte array. This is the code for saving the card into a byte array and serialize it.

```
public byte[] SaveAsByte()
    { 
        //Save this card in a file
        SerializedCard sc = new SerializedCard();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        sc.CardWidth = this.CardWidth;
        sc.CardHeight = this.CardHeight;
        sc.BackCard = this.backCard;
        sc.FrontCard = this.frontCard;


        formatter.Serialize(stream, sc);

        var arry = ConvertToArry(stream);
        stream.Close();
        this.NeedSave = false;

        return arry;
    }

private  byte[] ConvertToArry(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

My First question is that whenever I convert any stream object into byte array and try to get the array size, the result is zero??? I couldn't understand that. Is there anything wrong with the serialization process?

Any one could help?